# How to fresh install Debian to RAID0

Tags: linux, debian, installation, raid

I want to install a Debian variant to my notebook and I'm using the GUI installer.  The computer "only" has 31.2GB of internal storage but it also has a built-in micro SD card reader (that it can't boot from).  I'd like to use RAID-0 to fool the computer into thinking it has a single  94GB drive and install Debian on it.  It asks me if I'd like to configure RAID and I try to set it up as described.  When I go to install the OS I get the error:

```
No root file system
No root file system is defined.
Please correct this from the partitioning menu.
```

Hardware:

```
Asus TP200SA-UHBF
SanDisk Extreme PLUS 64GB microSDXC UHS-I Memory Card (SDSQXBZ-064G-ANCMA)
SanDisk Ultra Fit 32GB (SDCZ430-032G-A46)
```

Install summary:

```
Select a language: English
Selecct your location: United States
Configure the keyboard: American English
Non-free firmware install media: No
Configure the network: wlan0
(Enter user name and password to connect to home network)
Enter the hostname: asus
Domain name: localhost
(Enter account user name and password)
Timezone: Pacific
Force UEFI: No
Partition disks: Guided - use entire disk
Select the disk to partition: MMC/SC card #1 [internal storage]
Partition scheme: All files in one partition
Permanently erase any data: Yes
List of all partitions: Configure software RAID 
Format partition #1 as ext4 and #5 as swap: Yes
Software RAID configuration actions: Create MD device
Type: RAID0
Choose active devices: internal, swap, sdcard
Write the changes to the storage device and configure RAID: Yes
Software RAID configuration actions: Finish
List of all partitions: Finish partitioning and write changes to disk

No root file system
No root file system is defined.
Please correct this from the partitioning menu.
```

Comment: Have you actually got as far as setting up the RAID-0 in the installer? Normally after doing so a RAID device (e.g. ```/dev/md0```) appears and you tell it what filesystem to put on that. It seems like you haven't yet said where your root filesystem will go. This all sounds like a terrible idea BTW. A failure of EITHER device trashes your install.

Comment: They do get set up.  The partition list says "RAID0 devidce #0 - 95.1 GB Software RAID device"  I know there's a risk but with 31.2GB of internal storage I need to expand it however I can.

Comment: Normally at that point you click on / select the RAID member and it asks you how you want to use it. You'd choose to put root filesystem on it. Your error message is consistent with what happens when you don't actually do anything with it and have not specified where root filesystem goes.

Comment: I get a list like this:

\/ RAID0 device #0 - 95.1 GB Software RAID device
          >     #1          95.1 GB

If I double click the drive it lets me format it.  I tried that and got the same error.  If I try the Logical Volume Manager (LVM) I can try setting it up that way but no matter what I've chosen I get the same error.

Comment: Sorry but I keep saying, your error message is consistent with not having specified where the root filesystem will be, and you keep answering with things that don't include you specifying where the root filesystem will be. I feel like you may be missing that you have to click on the RAID device, select "use this as an ext4 filesystem", select mount point as "/" etc etc. If you haven't done all that, then that is the message that you get.

Comment: I've owned and used computers continuously since the 1970s.  I'm not a fool (in this case).  The installer does not provide an option to specify a mount point, as I said in my previous message.  I'd provide screen shots to prove it if I were able.  If you can demonstrate otherwise I'll be glad to try again and admit I'm wrong.

Comment: Okay, well it works for me, so I'm sorry for wasting your time